# Calling async method from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to working with web services, I am trying to implement a method, but I am having trouble. This is the method I am trying to get a response from:

```
(awaitable) Task<getIbuttonDataResponse> SpecSrvClient.getIbuttonDataAsync(GetIbuttonDataInput getIbuttonDataInput)

Usage:
getIbuttonDataResponse x = await getIbuttonDataAsync(...);
```

This is the WSDL generated code for "GetIbuttonDataInput"

```
public partial class GetIbuttonDataInput : object, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string ibuttonIdField;

    private string testerNameField;

    [SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string ibuttonId {
        get {
            return this.ibuttonIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.ibuttonIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ibuttonId");
        }
    }

    [SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string testerName {
        get {
            return this.testerNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.testerNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("testerName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I didn't realize I couldn't post images yet, so that messed me up.

My question is, when I attempt to get a response from the webservice, how do I pass the ibuttonIDField string? that is the value required to get a response.

EDIT 2:

Ok, so this is what I have written so far:

```
 static class Program
        {
        //...
        static void Main()
           {
            //...
            getIbuttonDataResponse x = new getIbuttonDataResponse();
            Response(serial, x);
            //...
            }
    static async void Response(string[] serial, getIbuttonDataResponse x)
          {
                iButtonDB_Service.SpecSrvClient testrequest = new SpecSrvClient();
                GetIbuttonDataInput input = new GetIbuttonDataInput { ibuttonId = serial[0], testerName = "me" };
                x = await testrequest.getIbuttonDataAsync(input);
           }
    }
```

I'm only getting a null return, but that could be because the database value it's trying to access is not created yet.

Comment: You didn't have an image attached. Please add it. Of post a link and I'll add it for you.

Comment: You will be getting a null return because you are not _returning_ anything. You are passing the `getIbuttonDataResponse` _into_ the `Response` method, not returning it from there. Try `static async Task<getIbuttonDataResponse> Response(string[] serial){... return await testrequest.getIbuttonDataAsync(input);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of it doesn't change just because the method is being called async. You still need to create an instance of the input object, populate it, then pass it to the service call:

```
GetIbuttonDataInput input = new GetIbuttonDataInput {ibuttonId ="x", testerName ="me"};
getIbuttonDataResponse x = await getIbuttonDataAsync(input);
```